# Dismiss popover with modal view controller inside

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

I have popover with navigation controller inside, then I present ABPeoplePickerNavigationController inside this popover via:

```
self.abPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.abPicker.modalInPopover = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:self.abPicker animated:YES];
```

The problem is that the popover can't be dismissed in this stage, when I press outside popover's area, nothing happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign a delegate (`peoplePickerDelegate`). Only the delegate events can dismiss the presented view controller, so you absolutely need the delegate. The delegate events will call `dismiss...` on the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

If you didn't want the resulting popover to be modal, then why did you present the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController with `presentModalViewController`? That is what it means to be modal! You are making it modal and then complaining it's modal; this is like hitting yourself in the face and then complaining your face is being hit. (Not to mention that you also set `modalInPopover` to YES, so you're hitting yourself in the face twice.)

The usual thing on iPad is to instantiate ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and use it directly as a new popover controller's view controller.

Comment: Yes, I have it (just missed the full code here), all delegate stuff is working, cancel button and contact selection.

Comment: But the standard behavior, when you press outside popover, it should disappear, is not working. I assume that I need to setup popover's delegate again for modal view controller, but I don't understand where.